# Append DOMDocument root element to another DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have 2 "DOMDocument" objects - $original and $additional. What I want is to take all children from $additional DOMDocument and append it to the end of $original document.

My plan was to take root element of the $additional document. I tried to use:

```
$root = $additional->documentElement;
$original->appendChild($root)
```

But I receive error that appendChild expect DOMNode object as an argument.
I tried to access each children of the document through:

```
$additional->childNodes->item(0);
```

But it returns object of DOMElement. Can you advice how to get object of DOMNode class? What is the most convenient way to provide this import operation?

$original XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product>
     <RecordReference>345345</RecordReference>
     <NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
     <NumberOfPages>100</NumberOfPages 
</Product>
```

$additional XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainSubject>
    <SubjectScheme>10</SubjectScheme>
</MainSubject>
```

What I want to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product>
     <RecordReference>345345</RecordReference>
     <NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
     <NumberOfPages>100</NumberOfPages>
     <MainSubject>
         <SubjectScheme>10</SubjectScheme>
     </MainSubject> 
</Product>
```

Comment: `DOMDocument` and `DOMElement` both extend `DOMNode`. What do your existing documents look like, and what is your desired end result?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I added samples of my xml

Answer (score 5):

A DOMElement is a DOMNode, DOMNode is the superclass. Here are several child classes for element, text and other nodes. Just iterate, import and append them.

```
$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->loadXML('<root/>');

$sourceDom = new DOMDocument();
$sourceDom->loadXml('<items><child/>TEXT</items>');

foreach ($sourceDom->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
  $targetDom->documentElement->appendChild(
    $targetDom->importNode($child, TRUE)
  );
}
```

This works with the document element, too.

```
$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->loadXML('<root/>');

$sourceDom = new DOMDocument();
$sourceDom->loadXml('<items><child/>TEXT</items>');

$targetDom->documentElement->appendChild(
  $targetDom->importNode($sourceDom->documentElement, TRUE)
);

echo $targetDom->saveXml();
```

`DOMDocument::importNode()` creates a copy of the provided node in the context of the document. Only nodes belonging to a document can be appended to it.

Comment: Thanks for example. I would like that <items></items> tag also will be included in the $targetDom. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tamara you just need to eliminate the foreach look and append child importing the document element of the source node.  `$targetDom->documentElement->appendChild($targetDom->importNode($sourceDom->documentElement, true));`

Comment: @SteveBuzonas Thanks, it works. Though I still don't get purpose of importNode function very well. Why I call it from target object?

Comment: @Tamara because the document is instantiated with metadata such as version and encoding.  Calling `importNode` on the target node ensures that the contents have compatible metadata on the nodes being imported.